# Be able to load Polymer on any existing page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am developing an extension which uses Polymer. If Polymer exists on the page, things start to break.
I am trying to figure out a solid strategy of loading Polymer in a way that doesn't conflict with the current page's Polymer (if one exists).

I am currently loading Polymer and my components as such:

```
  function loadRes(res) {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
        link.setAttribute('href', res);
        link.onload = function() {
          resolve(res);
        };
        document.head.appendChild(link);
      });
  }

  loadRes(chrome.extension.getURL("polymer/polymer.html")) 
  .then( loadRes(component1Url)) )
  .then( loadRes(component2Url)) )
  ...
```

In addition, I have a gulp job to obfuscate the names of all custom elements within the extension as such:

```
gulp.task('build:polymer', function(){
  gulp.src(polymer)
    .pipe(replace('Polymer', 'Polymer' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('dom-module', 'dom-module-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('custom-style', 'custom-style-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('dom-template', 'dom-template-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('dom-repeat', 'dom-repeat-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('array-selector', 'array-selector-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('dom-if', 'dom-if-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(replace('dom-bind', 'dom-bind-' + APP_KEY))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/polymer'));
});
```

I realize this is ugly but this is a last resort type of solution. The above works in most sites which use polymer but still cause unexpected issues - I suspect due to other stuff being bound to `window`.

Is there a cleaner way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rob Dodson code for conditionally load Polymer in [zuperkulblog-progressive](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive).
He explained  at Chrome Dev Summit 2015  [here](https://youtu.be/g7f1Az5fxgU?t=9m20s)

```js
// 4. Conditionally load the webcomponents polyfill if needed by the browser.
// This feature detect will need to change over time as browsers implement
// different features.
var webComponentsSupported = ('registerElement' in document && 'import' in document.createElement('link') && 'content' in document.createElement('template'));

if (!webComponentsSupported) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
  script.onload = finishLazyLoading;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
  finishLazyLoading();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeanPokou but I still need to load Polymer in such a way that doesn't conflict with a page's existing version of Polymer (if any). That is my real challenge. I am loading all of this via an extension and my extension does not know if Polymer already exists on the page or not.